# request data and print results

Tags: performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

On last test, the below code takes approximately 10 seconds to download then print the data from 10 url's. I wish to speed this up as much as possible as later on I plan to expand this further and use the scraped data as live data in a GUI.

The display_value() function consists of 95% of the time, which seems like an awful lot considering it's a small number. I am thinking it's due to how I've written the function call, but out of ideas.

```
def live_indices():
    import sys
    """Acquire stock value from Yahoo Finance using stock symbol as key. Then assign the relevant variable to the respective value.
    ie. 'GSPC' equates to the value keyed to 'GSPC' stock indices_price_value.
    """
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()  # Use to time how long the function takes to complete
    import requests
    import bs4

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36'}

    all_indices_values = {}
    symbols = ['GSPC', 'DJI', 'IXIC', 'FTSE', 'NSEI', 'FCHI', 'N225', 'GDAXI', 'IMOEX.ME', '000001.SS']
    for ticker in symbols:
        url = f'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/lookup/all?s={ticker}'
        tmp_res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        tmp_res.raise_for_status()
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(tmp_res.text, 'html.parser')
        indices_price_value = soup.select('#Main tbody>tr td')[2].text

        all_indices_values[ticker] = indices_price_value

    end_time = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
    sys.stdout.write(f'DONE - time taken = {end_time}'.upper())


    return all_indices_values

def display_value(live_indices):
    print(live_indices['GSPC'])
    print(live_indices['DJI'])
    print(live_indices['IXIC'])
    print(live_indices['FTSE'])
    print(live_indices['NSEI'])
    print(live_indices['FCHI'])
    print(live_indices['N225'])
    print(live_indices['GDAXI'])
    print(live_indices['IMOEX.ME'])
    print(live_indices['000001.SS'])

display_value(live_indices())
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/279880/revisions#rev-body-85832cfb-b58f-4a99-9ce6-9b9db4701532) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your profiling potentially is misleading. Neither 10 prints nor accessing 10 dictionary keys should take upwards 10 seconds. Maybe try profiling again with something like

```
def display_values(live_indices):
    for key in SYMBOLS:
        print(key)

all_indices_values = live_indices()
display_values(all_indices_values)
```

Now, to actually speed up the requests you will have to use parallelism. You are currently doing sequential requests, which understandably takes forever since you have to wait for each scrape to finish before starting the next one.

You can probably also look for some API instead of scraping web pages for the data; that should decrease the payload by quite a bit.

If you do not already know, there are modules for both [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) and for [timing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) built into the standard library - you don't need to manually try to time stuff.